# Milkmangames Admob extension error

Tags: admob

When the fallowing code is executed :
    var testDevices:Vector.;
    testDevices=AdMob.getTestDeviceIDs();
    AdMob.showAd(AdMobAdType.BANNER,AdMobAlignment.CENTER,AdMobAlignment.TOP,testDevices);
...the aplication instaled on my IPAD crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the testDevices junk altogether and try it that way. This is a function meant specifically for testing purposes using that ANE. But, if it is what is causing your error, just throw it out.

Try this:

AdMob.showAd(AdMobAdType.BANNER,AdMobAlignment.CENTER,AdMobAlignment.TOP,null);

(remember to also delete the variable testDevices)

Comment: Also, make sure you have done the AdMob.init function before this.